# Cannot find link using Capybara and Rspec while writing an integration test

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, rspec-rails

I am trying to find a link by CSS classes and ids but always getting an error: `Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find css ...`

The actual piece of code is:

```
find('#bucket_resources_containers > #user_base_widget.widget > 
div.widget_header > div.right.may-
edit.control.button.add.icon.add_options > a.tasksy.options').click
```

The page source is: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHHIi.png)

Comment: Since the element you're trying to click on has no contents, does it actually have any size on the page?  If not it will be considered non-visible.  Also, using selectors that specific is just going to make your tests really brittle, at the very least one of the id selectors shouldn't be needed since the other should still be uniquely identifying an element, and most of the clases you're specifying are probably unnecessary.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole, I understand that it should be something like `find('#bucket_resources_containers > #user_base_widget > div > div > a').click`, but finds only the first div element `'#bucket_resources_containers`.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole That elements were not visible. Everything works fine know.

Comment: Actually It should be whatever is the minimum relevant selector to uniquely identify the element you want - In the shown case, and assuming I'm guessing what the different classes mean correctly, I would probably do something like . `find('#user_base_widget .widget_header .add_options a.options')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gave us the answer in your comment, the element was not visible.

**Short answer**: `find_link(selector, visible: :all).click`

As capybara shows in the [documentation](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#the-dsl):

> *By default Capybara will only locate visible elements. This is because a real user would not be able to interact with non-visible elements*.

Only locate visible elements is an smart design of capybara, it avoids thinking that a user would be able to find the element.

The `find_link` [method documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#find_link-instance_method) doesn't help much when finding for hidden links because it only show these options: `wait, href, id, title, alt, class`:

```
#find_link([locator], options = {}) ⇒ Capybara::Node::Element
```

But you see on the [finding documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/master#finding) there was a `visible` option:

```
find_link('Hello', :visible => :all).visible?
find_link(class: ['some_class', 'some_other_class'], :visible => :all).visible?
```

This option `visible` comes from `#all` method, [where you can see here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#all-instance_method). It can have these values:

```
true - only finds visible elements.
false - finds invisible and visible elements.
:all - same as false; finds visible and invisible elements.
:hidden - only finds invisible elements.
:visible - same as true; only finds visible elements.
```

So, in your case, you could use `visible: false`, if you really mean it to be hidden, or `visible: :all` if you don't care about the visibility.